# First time using C++/CLI and getting compiler error in class definition

Tags: c++, c++-cli, clr

I'm trying to create a wrapper class for a C# dll and am coming across a compiler error in my definition. I've tried finding a solution and reading MSDN help but so far nothing works.

```
Error   2   error C2059: syntax error : 'public' 7
Error   3   error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '{' 8
Error   4   error C2447: '{' : missing function header (old-style formal list?) 8
Error   5   error C2059: syntax error : 'public' 7
Error   6   error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '{' 8
Error   7   error C2447: '{' : missing function header (old-style formal list?) 8
```

ASComms.h

```
#pragma once

#include "IPADDRESS.h"

namespace DataComms
{
    public ref class CASComms 
    {
    public: 
        void Connect(IPADDRESS ipaddr);
        void Write(const char* plcTAG, const char* data);

    private:
        AutomatedSolutions::Win::Comm::AB::Logix::Net::Channel ^m_channel;
        AutomatedSolutions::Win::Comm::AB::Logix::Device ^m_device;
        AutomatedSolutions::Win::Comm::AB::Logix::Group ^m_group;
        AutomatedSolutions::Win::Comm::AB::Logix::Item ^m_item;
    };
}
```

ASComms.cpp

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "ASComms.h"
#include "IPADDRESS.h"


using namespace AutomatedSolutions::Win::Comm::AB::Logix;

void DataComms::CASComms::Connect(IPADDRESS ipaddr)
{
    // do stuff
}

void DataComms::CASComms::Write(const char* plcTAG, const char* data)
{
    // do stuff
}
```

Comment: I originally didn't have "public class" and just had "class" but had a whole host of other errors. Then i found some tutorials which said to put the public there.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude `public ref class CASComms` seems valid C++/CLI to me and the compiler. You probably created a normal unmanaged C++ project instead of a managed C++/CLI one.

Comment: Are you sure you have created a C++/CLI project? It's not a plain C++ project? The errors you get *are* from the header file? From the line `public ref class CASComms`?

Comment: The most obvious reason for these syntax errors is that you did not actually create a C++/CLI project.  Or the /clr option is not turned on for whatever source file that #included that .h file.

Comment: Thanks I've got it fixed now. I had accidentally included that .h file in another file which didn't have the /clr option turned on.